# NSApplication delegate and Preference Panes

Tags: cocoa, macos, delegates

It seems that I can't control the NSApp delegate from within a System Preferences pane, which is understandable. Is there any other way I can have my object notified when the program becomes active?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most delegate methods in the Cocoa frameworks are simply notification methods. This includes `application{Will,Did}{Become,Resign}Active:`, which are notification methods for `NSApplication{Will,Did}{Become,Resign}ActiveNotification`. The notifications are in the same place as the delegate methods: [the NSApplication documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000012-BAJJDFEC).

So, just sign up for those notifications on the local `NSNotificationCenter`.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I'm using this notification in conjunction with FSEvents to refresh an NSTableView. According to my debugging, everything works exactly as it should until I call setDataSource on the view. The view just doesn't update. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: None. You should post another question with more details.

Answer (score 3):

NSPreferencePane gives you a few methods you can override to respond to changes. In particular, `mainViewDidLoad:` gives you a chance to do initialization when your preference pane becomes active for the first time.

If you actually meant you want to keep track of when the System Preferences window becomes main or key, you can subscribe to NSWindow's notifications for those events.

```
//  These messages get sent to the a preference panel just before and
//  just after it becomes the currently selected preference panel.
- (void) willSelect;
- (void) didSelect;

//  The willUnselect message gets sent to the currently selected preference panel
//  just before and just after it gets swapped out for another preference panel
- (void) willUnselect;
- (void) didUnselect;
```